# Does an 8-bit timer take same time as a 16-bit timer to overflow in microcontroller?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, avr

I want to call a function after certain time, irrespective of the other code, so which timer should I select

Comment: your title question.  if I can only have one decimal digit how many seconds can I count to?  9  if I have two I can count to 99 seconds, so is a 9 second overflow and a 99 second overflow take the same amount of time?  NO absolutely not.

Comment: One thing has nothing to do with the other.  How often it overflows and which one you may or may not be able to use for your design are affected by what the features are for each timer.  Is there a prescaler?  Based on combinations of the prescaler and rollover trigger features of each timer can you find a combination that meets the interval you are after?  Sometimes you can with either, sometimes you need more bits to get more accuracy.  And sometimes an included 8 bit timer is a different design altogether than a 16 bit timer in the same chip.

Comment: If you clock it 256 times slower, yes.

Answer (score 4):

When working with timers in microcontrollers you often have to set their prescaler first. This devides the clock frequency of your mcu. Depending on the values you can set in the prescaller you could have the 8bit timer run shorter, longer or for the same amount of time as the 16 bit timer. Please check the manual of your microcontroller for the available settings.